# Monitor progress of scikit's DBSCAN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I have a large amount of data that I want to cluster with [Scikit's DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html). I do it with the following line:

```
dbscanObject = DBSCAN(eps=20, min_samples=15).fit(featureVectors)
```

Unfortunately, this takes very long depending on how large the dataset is, and I see no way to monitor the progress of DBSCAN. How can I monitor the algorithm's progress and estimate the time left for the algorithm to finish?

Comment: If you can use keras wrappers look into [callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/) from fit function. Here is an [example repo.](https://github.com/stared/livelossplot)

Comment: To add `callbacks` are currently not part of Scikit-learn but its part of the roadmap. Here's a [feature discussion on the same.](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10973)

Comment: @NihalSangeeth It would be very helpful if you'd add an answer with a simple example with Keras wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This model of scikit still does not support a progress bar.
Models which support it are https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble